# Is it possible to use the output of bundle show command as an argument of cd?

Tags: command-line, ubuntu-16.04, jekyll

I am working with jekyll(a static site generator), and frequently need to navigate the gem source, which is buried under plenty of sub directories, autocomplete by hitting tab key helps but it would be wonderful if I could somehow append the output of

```
bundle show minima
```

which on my laptop results in

> /home/username/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/minima-2.1.1

to the change directory command `cd`. so that the resulting command becomes

```
cd /home/username/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/minima-2.1.1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cd "$(bundle show minima)"
```

The trick is: in modern shells `$(foo)` is substituted with the output of `foo`. The alternative syntax is:

```
cd "`bundle show minima`"
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me:

1. Installed xclip : `sudo apt install xclip`
2. pipe the output of `bundle` command to clipboard: `bundle show minima | xclip -sel c`
3. type `cd` and press `ctrl+shift+v`